# Why do the topic buttons in a chat room give me a 404?

Tags: support, chat

In the SOCVR chat room, if I click the 'discussion' or 'moderation' buttons (right side of the page and above the room), it shows 'Page not found'. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because those "buttons" are actually [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) in the description of the room:

[image]

If you look at the URL that the [moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderation) button/tag directs to, you'll see this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/moderation/info
```

As there is no [moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderation) tag on Stack Overflow, you get that 404.

As a side note, it doesn't seem too uncommon to use nonexistent tags in chat. For example, look at the tags for the SE chatroom, [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq):

[image]

It is clearly not very useful as a proper tag on the site, but informative and entertaining nonetheless.

---

It is currently not possible to have a chat room's description tags point to the Meta site. The form for adding tags for a chat room only allows the *names* of a tag - you do not have any control of the syntax or location.

[image]

You can use the `[meta-tag:my-tag]` syntax pretty much everywhere else, just not in the chat room's description.

Comment: It's too bad you can't specify they are tags for the meta site.

Comment: I thought you could @gunr2171 - with `[meta-tag:moderation]` to get [meta-tag:moderation].  Does that not work in chat?

Comment: [No that doesn't work in chat](https://i.imgur.com/MfAg2gR.png). You only have the text of the tags, not any sort of syntax.

Comment: [It seems to work in chat proper](https://i.imgur.com/WRYK22N.png), using it in the [Sandbox room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox). Guess different rules apply for descriptions if you can't do that for SOCVR?

Comment: I mean, even if you can tag meta tags, I don't think "programmatic-crowbars" is a very often discussed meta topic. I would be happy to change that...

Comment: @Makoto see my FR on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242307/can-we-have-meta-tags-for-chatrooms